# Marshalling char arrays in Struct for windows CE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pinvoke

How would one marshal the char arrays in the following struct definition? in the .Net CompactFramework (For Windows CE)

//Struct of request for transaction

```
typedef struct _VXN_REQUEST
{

    char        DID [33]; 
    char        MID [33]; 
    char        TID [33];  
    char        ClientRef [33]; 
    char        Payload [8192];
    ULONG       PayloadLength;
} VXN_REQUEST, *LPVXN_REQUEST;
```

I tried to Marshal it like this but it doesn't seem to work

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct VXN_REQUEST
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
            public string DID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
            public string MID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
            public string TID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
            public string ClientRef;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
            public string Payload;
            public uint PayloadLength;

        }
```

Also Tried like This but none of them works, the native code is taking it as a single char instead.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct VXN_REQUEST
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 33)]

    public char[] DID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 33)]

    public char[] MID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 33)]

    public char[] TID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 33)]

    public char[] ClientRef;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 33)]

    public char[] Payload;
    public uint PayloadLength;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A .NET char takes two bytes, it stores a Unicode codepoint encoded in utf-16.  Use byte instead of char in the declaration.  Use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() to fill the byte[] if you actually need these fields to be strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change your P/Invoke declaration to take in a byte[] instead of the struct, then define it like this:

```
public class VXN_REQUEST 
{
    private byte[] m_data;

    public const int Size = 8328;

    public VXN_REQUEST()
    {
        m_data = new byte[Size];
    }

    public static implicit operator byte[](VXN_REQUEST req)
    {
        return req.m_data;
    }

    public string DID
    {
        get { return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_data, 0, 33).Trim('\0'); }
        set 
        { 
            // TODO: verify that 'value' isn't too long
            // first clear the contents
            var empty = new byte[33];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(empty, 0, m_data, 0, empty.Length);
            // copy data
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value).CopyTo(m_data, 0); 
        }
    }

    public string MID
    {
        get { return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_data, 33, 33).Trim('\0'); }
    }

    public string TID
    {
        get { return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_data, 66, 33).Trim('\0'); }
    }

    public string ClientRef
    {
        get { return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_data, 99, 33).Trim('\0'); }
    }

    public string Payload
    {
        get { return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_data, 132, PayloadLength).Trim('\0'); }
    }

    public int PayloadLength
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToInt32(m_data, 8324); }
    }
}
```

And for the record, 33-charater lengths seems really odd to me.

Comment: Thanks Ctacke, I am thinking this may  work but why are the properties read only, I need to pass the values to the native.

Comment: I edited the code and added a setter for the DID member.  Just copy that into the other properties, adjust the offsets and length for Payload.

Comment: Ctackle , will this class directly get marshaled to the native struct

Comment: same as the struct, like this [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
            ref VXN_REQUEST lpVxnRequest,   some how it doesn't seem to pass  the values to the native codes. will the did,mid and so on strings be able to get marshaled to the nativecode as char[] ,in the .netcompact framework   Thanks

Comment: you're marshalling a btye array, not the struct.  If it's not coming across right, then I question the declaration - again the 33 byte char arrays are questionable.

Comment: Ctackle: I have the following function which uses the vxnrequest function, with the changes you made to the vxnreques, any suggestions how to peroperly pass the vxnrequest byte[] in here.

Comment: [DllImport("VXNAPI_CE.dll", EntryPoint = "VxnSimpleTransaction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
        public static extern int VxnSimpleTransaction(    
            [In] byte[] ServiceID,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
            ref VXN_REQUEST lpVxnRequest,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
            ref VXN_RESPONSE lpVxnResponse);     Thanks.

Comment: and here is the native code:                        VxnSimpleTransaction (const char* svc_name, 
                   const LPVXN_REQUEST query, 
                   LPVXN_RESPONSE  response) Thanks

Comment: Again, the p/ invoke should marshal a byte[], not the struct name (replace ref VXN_REQUEST with byte[])

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, I got it working by declaring the struct with byte arrays fileds, and intilizing them to there size when ever we create the instance of the vxn request